# React slow/freezing on IE and Edge

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, reactjs

I have a `react.js` app that runs fine on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

However it lags heavily and sometimes freezes on any version of Internet Explorer. Is there away to speed it up on IE? This seems like more than an optimization issue and the difference between Chrome and IE is drastic.

Extra Info:
I have tested on IE 9-11 as well as Edge, and all seem to have this issue. It is slow and laggy in general but freezes or lags incredibly on a `hover` event.

Comment: React isn't slow by itself in these browsers we would have to see the code

Comment: Is Facebook.com lagging too? :)

Comment: For the record, using the production version of React instead of development version makes a huge difference in IE that you dont really notice in others.